# How to check if a product is salable using isSalable()?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I am trying to use plugin to override `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart.php` - `addOrderItem function`

Instead of getting item's quantity, how to check if product is salable using isSalable()? Is there any way to use product id to get if product is isSalable().

```
public function aroundAddOrderItem($subject, callable $proceed, $orderItem, $qtyFlag = null)
    {
        if ($orderItem->getParentItem() === null) {
            $sku = $orderItem->getSku();
            $productId=$this->product->getIdBySku($sku);
            $productStock = $this->stockItemRepository->get($productId);
            $productQty = $productStock->getQty();
            
            if($productQty < 1)
            {
                return $this;
            }
            else
            {
                return $proceed($orderItem, $qtyFlag);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can check  product is isSalable by below code using SKU.

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
    $sku = $orderItem->getSku();
    $salable = $objectManager->create('Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku')->execute($sku);
    foreach ($salable as $key => $value) {
         $salableQty = $value['qty'];
     }
```

**You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**

Comment: can I not use isSalable() something like $product->isSalable()?